# How to output numbers to each iteration in a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x

```
for replay_data in raw_replay_data['data']['video_info']:
    target.write("Coordinates: " + replay_data['lat'] + (',') + replay_data['lnt'] + "\n")
```

This for loop gives me fx. the output of:

```
Coordinates: 0,0
Coordinates: 0,0
Coordinates: 0,0
Coordinates: 0,0
```

I would like a number after each "Coordinates" string that increases for each new coordinates available.
How can I make it output:

```
Coordinates 1: 0,0
Coordinates 2: 0,0
Coordinates 3: 0,0
Coordinates 4: 0,0
```

Comment: If you've found an answer useful, please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the tick mark next to it, so that others may find it useful in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a counter and count up:

```
numbr = 1   # counter, starting at 1
for replay_data in raw_replay_data['data']['video_info']:
    target.write("Coordinates " + str(numbr) + ": " + replay_data['lat'] + (',') + replay_data['lnt'] + "\n")
    numbr += 1 # increment counter
```

You might want to look into string format methods: [string.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html?highlight=string%20format#string.Formatter)

You can do things like:

```
replay_data = {}
replay_data['lat'] = 1
replay_data['lnt'] = 2

numbr = 22

print("Coordinates {n}: {lat},{lng}\n"
      .format(n=numbr, lat = replay_data['lat'], lng = replay_data['lnt']))
```

Output:

```
Coordinates 22: 1,2
```

Answer (score 4):

Look up the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), it's your best friend in for loops.  Also you can use some [`str.format()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to make your output more readable:

```
for index, replay_data in enumerate(raw_replay_data['data']['video_info']):
    target.write("Coordinates {0}: {1}, {2}\n".format(index+1, replay_data['lat'], replay_data['lnt'])
```